# How is entanglement possible?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

If one particle is dependent on the other how can an action on one particle affect the state of another if when you measure a particle, the result you see is based off of something that technically hasn't happened yet?

Comment: Have you tried [searching this site for *entanglement*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=entanglement). This and related questions have been asked many, many times before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there such a thing as "Action at a distance"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2206/)

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was thinking each particle has a state. If that were the case they would not be entangled. What happens is you have a joint state for the pair of particles.

Since it starts out a joint state, when you act on the state you act on a joint state so it affects  the joint state.

And yes, what we call an observation or a measurement changes the (joint) state (or even the individual state if it has one).

Comment: They have a state when they are measured though.

Comment: There are different kinds of measurements. Some measurements on the joint space actually place the joint system into an entangled state.